# Set of all real values of $\lambda$ for which quadratic equation $(\lambda ^2+1)x^2-4\lambda x+2=0$ always has exactly one root in $(0,1)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

> > Set of all real values of $\lambda$ for which quadratic equation $(\lambda ^2+1)x^2-4\lambda x+2=0$ always has exactly one root in interval $(0,1)$

**My Approach:**
Let $f(x)=(\lambda ^2+1)x^2-4\lambda x+2$

Since exactly one root lies between $(0,1)$ so we must have $f(0)f(1)<0$

Using above condition I got an answer $\lambda\in (1,3)$.

Case $1$ Checking at $\lambda =1$. I got two equal roots $1,1$.

Case $2$ Checking at $\lambda = 3$.  I got two roots $\dfrac{1}{5}, 1$

As in Case $2$ one root lies in $(0,1)$

**My Doubt:** Why we always check at boundary point.

Is there any rule for this?

I mean in which question I should check and in which question i shouldn't.

Comment: What about the possibility of a **repeated root**?  The repeated root will occur if and only if $$16\lambda^2 - 8(\lambda^2 + 1) = 0 \iff$$ $$\lambda^2 - 1 = 0.$$  So, the two values of $\lambda \in \{-1,1\}$ must be manually checked.